# Can't line up the item list horizontally using flex-box & styled-components

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, jsx, styled-components

I want line up items in item-list.

This is item-list block and css

```
const ItemListBlock = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    width: 90%;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
`;


<ItemListBlock>
        <div>
            {items.map(item => (
                <Item className="item" item={item} key={item.id} />
            ))}
        </div>
</ItemListBlock>
```

and This is item block and css (It's a little abbreviated.)

```
const PostItemBlock = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    width: 352px;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
    
    p {
        margin-top: 2rem;
    }
    h3 {
        width: 352px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        
    }
    
    .subdesc {
        align-self: flex-end;
    }
`;


const Item = ({ item }) => {
    return (
        <ItemBlock>
            <h3>
               title.
            </h3>
            <p1 className="subdesc">subdesc.</p1>
        </ItemBlock>
    );
};
```

I want display item list like this :
[image]

But It actually display like this :
[image]

I wrote flex-direction:row. But It still line up vertically. How can I line up items horizontally??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostItemBlock should be inline currently it is block: Change it to `display: inline-flex`